# Feedback on ranking algorithm options for my website

Tags: algorithm, math, ranking

I am currently working on writing an algorithm for my new site I plan to launch soon. The index page will display the "hottest" posts at the moment.
Variables to consider are:

- Number of votes
- How controversial the post is (# between 0-1)
- Time since post

I have come up with two possible algorithms, the first and most simple is:

```
controversial * (numVotesThisHour / (numVotesTotal - numVotesThisHour)
Denom = numVotesTuisHour if numVotesTotal - numVotesThisHour == 0
```

*Highest number is hottest*

My other option is to use an algorithm similar to Reddit's (except that the score decreases as time goes by):

```
[controversial * log(x)] - (TimePassed / interval)
x = { numVotesTotal if numVotesTotal >= 10, 10 if numVotesTotal < 10
```

*Highest number is hottest*

The first algorithm would allow older posts to become "hot" again in the future while the second one wouldn't.

So my question is, which one of these two algorithms do you think is more effective? Which one do you think will display the truly "hot" topics at the moment? Can you think of any advantages or disadvantages to using one over the other? I just want to make sure I don't overlook anything so that I can ensure the content is as relevant as possible. Any feedback would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily an answer to your question, but have a look at Hacker News ranking algorithm : http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1781013

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the context of the website? If it's something like recipe submissions then I'd say you'd want older posts to be able to become "hot." On the flip side if it's posts about news articles then I'd say that no we wouldn't want older submissions to become hot. Who wants to hear about how Bush won the election years ago when there's newer news out there?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something. In the first formula you have numVotesTotal in the denominator. So higher number of votes all time will mean it will never be so hot even if it is not so old.

For example if I have two posts - P1 and P2 (both equally controversial). Say P1 has numVotesTotal = 20, and P2 has numVotesTotal = 1000. Now in the last one hour  P1 gets numVotesThisHour = 10 and P2 gets numVotesThisHour = 200.

According to the algorithm, P1 is more famous than P2. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: (Assuming controversial == 1) If P1 gets 10 votes and already has 20 votes, its score is 1/2. If P2 gets 200 votes and already has 1000, its score is 1/5. Perhaps not the best idea, but this is what I was looking for. My intention was that a post that saw the greatest proportional increase would be ranked highest. Like I said, it may not be a good solution for my website, but I don't know. Do you think, from a user's point of view, this would be effective or not so great?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first algorithm relies too heavily on instantaneous trend. Think of NASCAR, the current leader could be going 0 m.p.h. because he's at a pit stop. The second one uses the notion of average trend. I think both have their uses.

So for two posts with the same total votes and controversial rating, but where posts one receives 20 votes in the first hour and zero in the second, while the other receives 10 in each hour. The first post will be buried by the first algorithm but the second algorithm will rank them equally.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but I think the 'hotness' is entirely dependent on the time frame, and not at all on the total votes unless your time frame is 'all time'. Also, it seems to me that the *proportion* of all votes in the relevant time frame, rather than the absolute number of them, is the important figure.

You might have several categories of hot:

- Hottest this hour
- Hottest this week
- Hottest since your last visit
- Hottest all time

So, 'Hottest in the last [whatever]' could be calculated like this:

```
votes_for_topic_in_timeframe / all_votes_in_timeframe
```

if you especially want a number between 0 and 1, (useful for comparing across categories) or, if you only want the ones in a specific timeframe, just take the `votes_for_topic_in_timeframe` values and sort into descending order.

If you don't want the user explicitly choosing the time frame, you may want to calculate all (say) four versions (or perhaps just the top 3), assign a multiplier to each category to give each category a relative importance, and calculate total values for each topic to take the top *n*. This has the advantage of potentially hiding from the user that no-one at all has voted in the last hour ;)

Comment: I'm ignoring the controversy multiplier; just multiply by it as well if required.